# How to send news to specific subscribers with specific tags?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I have database with subscribers which are subscribed to specific tags and new news which are need to be sent to subscribers. I need to write command on Symfony 4 that will do it. I already have this code:

```
class SubscribeLauncherCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected static $defaultName = 'app:subscribe-launcher';
    private $mailer;
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, \Swift_Mailer $mailer)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->em = $em;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $news = $this->em->getRepository(News::class)->findBy(array(), array('date_created' => 'DESC'));
        $subscribers = $this->em->getRepository(NewsSubscribe::class)->findBy(array('confirmed' => true));
        $tags = $this->em->getRepository(Tag::class)->findAll();
        $first_new_date = $news[0]->getDateCreated();
        /** @var NewsSubscribe $subscribers */
        /** @var \Swift_Message $message */
        foreach ($subscribers as $subscriber) {
            foreach ($news as $new)
            {
                if ($new->getDateCreated() < $first_new_date) {
                    $message = (new \Swift_Message('Test Email'))
                        ->setFrom('send@example.com')
                        ->setTo($subscriber->getEmail())
                        ->setBody(
                            'test',
                            'text/html');
                    $first_new_date = $new->getDateCreated();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. Can you please help?

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work"? Are you getting any error message? What result are you expecting?

Comment: The problem is that it does not rely on tags and new news, I don't know how to tie together tags, new news and subscribers. It must send only news which are newly created and with specific tags. I expect that it must not send it to all emails and all subscribers, but rather only specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I take it subscribers have a collection of tags they are subscribed to and news is related to a tag.

If that is the case you need to add a couple of conditions in your loop, something like :

```
 foreach ($subscribers as $subscriber) {
        $subscribedTags = $subscriber->getSubscribedTags();
        foreach ($news as $new)
        {
            if ($new->getDateCreated() < $first_new_date) {
                $relatedTag = $new->getTag();
                if(in_array($relatedTag, $subscribedTags)){ //Check if the user is subscribed to the particular tag of this news
                    ...Send the email...
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What should we do if there are news with a couple of tags?

Comment: in that case you would use :
$relatedTags = $new-> getTags();
if(sizeof(array_intersect($subscribedTags, $relatedTags) > 0) {
...
}

Comment: Thank you, that's great!